# How is it possible to place an Angular 2 app at anywhere but the root path?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm building a Web site that has an Angular (2) SPA as a component, using ui-router-ng2. I'd like to do something like:

- http://example.com/ -> Default (static) home page, with a link to the SPA
- http://example.com/app -> SPA
- Anything else -> Static pages

So the route "foo.bar" should have the URL "/app/#/foo/bar". My server (written in Go) properly handles the routing, but the SPA replaces the addresses with paths relative to the root, instead of "/app" ("/#/foo/bar" instead of "/app/#/foo/bar"). How do I tell Angular where I want the SPA to live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set base tag in head :

```
<base href="http://your-app/root-angular-path/">
```

Or you can set it directly in your App Module :

```
// >= Angular2 RC.6 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [RouterModule], 
  providers: [
   {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : 'http://my-app/angular/' },
   {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} },
  ]
]);
```